# Objective-C OOP init function

Tags: objective-c, oop

The book I am reading says that after allocating an object I need to call the init function on the instance. However, I did not see any differences in the functionality of the class when I don't call the init method. So what exactly is the init function doing ? Below is the interface for the simple class:

```
@interface Fraction: NSObject
{
   int numerator;

   int denominator;
}
-(void) print;

-(void) setNumerator: (int) num;

-(void) setDenominator:(int) den ;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`init` is meant to initialize all necessary instance variables so that the object is in a defined state. After `alloc`, all ivars are set to `0`/`nil`/`NULL`, which might not be a permitted state for your object (for example, `denominator` should never be `0`).

The `init` method your class inherited from `NSObject` does nothing so if your class does not need to initialize any ivars you don't have to implement your own. But it is good custom to *always* call `init` right after `alloc`, even if you know the method does nothing (who says this will remain true forever?).

Answer (score 1):

> allocating an object I need to call the init function on the instance

can be treated as

> allocating an object I should call the init function on the
>   instance

**Init is generally used to initialize instance variables within the class.**

In the init method of the NSObject class, no initialization takes place, it simply returns self .